# how to set a password for particular file in linux system?

Tags: linux

I am using ubuntu 12.0 machine. I want to set a password
for particular file.

Whenever I open that file, the system should ask the password. 
If the password is wrong, don't open that file.

I searched in net. Some sites explain how to set a password 
using "cryptkeeper" gem. But, for install that gem needs root
privilege. But I am not a root user.

So, anybody know how to do this using a linux command itself ?

Comment: You can encrypt this file with any script, which doesn't need root privileges, but there is no such tool in standard linux distributive

Answer (score 1):

In general I know of no way to do this. Your best bet is to encrypt with something like `gpg -c important.docx` and decrypt the file when you need it with `gpg important.docx.gpg`.

[Here is a general tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-encryptdecrypt-a-file-in-linux-with-gpg/).

Answer (score 0):

You is not a root and you wish to password protect some directories?
Its impossible.